# Conditional formating if cell is a formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to have cells which value has been entered manually and cells that are the result of a formula differently, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **custom formula: `=ISFORMULA(A1)` or: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)), (NOT(ISFORMULA(A1))))`**

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to format all cells in the sheet. With this solution I can only make one column at a time (for instance by selecting column A and writing =ISFORMULA($A1)). For the whole sheet I wouldn't know what to put into the brackets.

Comment: @kaleidoscop you will put the same but you will apply it to the whole range. eg instead of `A1:A`, type in `A1:Z`